# How to find out StandardScaling parameters .mean_ and .scale_ when using Column Transformer from Scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, standardization

I want to apply StandardScaler only to the numerical parts of my dataset using the function `sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer`, (the rest is already one-hot encoded). I would like to see `.scale_` and `.mean_` parameters fitted to the training data, but the function `scaler.mean_` and `scaler.scale_` obviously does not work when using a column transformer. Is there a way to do so?

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42, stratify=y)

scaler = StandardScaler()
data_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
 ('numerical', scaler, numerical_variables)], remainder='passthrough')

X_train = data_pipeline.fit_transform(X_train)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fitted transformers are available in the attributes `transformers_` (a list) and `named_transformers_` (a dict-like with keys the names you provided).  So, for example,

```py
data_pipeline.named_transformers_['numerical'].mean_
```